How does DatePick in antd 3.x support manual input of numbers and formatting?
Manually enter a number, such as 20230212, formatted as 2023-02-12
I can't get the value of DatePick input，There is no case online about antd 3.x DatePick supporting manual input of numbers，Is there any great god who can answer this question?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
